# Best practice to pass PyTorch device name to model

Tags: pytorch

Currently, I separated `train.py` with `model.py` for my deep learning project.

So for the datasets, they are sent to cuda device inside the **`epoch for loop`** like below.

`train.py`

```
...
device = torch.device('cuda:2' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = MyNet(~).to(device)
...
for batch_data in train_loader:
    s0 = batch_data[0].to(device)
    s1 = batch_data[1].to(device)
    pred = model(s0, s1)
```

However, inside my model (in model.py), it also needs to access the **device variable** for skip connection like method. To make a new copy of hidden unit (for residual connection)

`model.py`

```
class MyNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_feats, hid_feats, out_feats):
        super(MyNet, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = GCNConv(in_feats, hid_feats)
        ...

    def forward(self, data):
        x, edge_index = data.x, data.edge_index
        x1 = copy.copy(x.float())
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
        skip_conn = torch.zeros(len(data.batch), x1.size(1)).to(device)  # <--
        (some opps for x1 -> skip_conn)
        x = torch.cat((x, skip_conn), 1)
```

In this case, I am currently passing `device` as a parameter, however, I believe this is not a best practice.

1. Where should be the best practice to send the dataset to CUDA?
2. In the case of multiple scripts need to access `device`, how sould I handle this? (parameter, global variable?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new attribute to `MyModel` to store the `device` info and use this in the `skip_conn` initialization.

```
class MyNet(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, in_feats, hid_feats, out_feats, device): # <--
    super(MyNet, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = GCNConv(in_feats, hid_feats)
    self.device = device # <--
    self.to(self.device) # <--
    ...

def forward(self, data):
    x, edge_index = data.x, data.edge_index
    x1 = copy.copy(x.float())
    x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
    skip_conn = torch.zeros(len(data.batch), x1.size(1), device=self.device)  # <--
    (some opps for x1 -> skip_conn)
    x = torch.cat((x, skip_conn), 1)
```

Notice that in this example, `MyNet` is responsible for all the device logic including the `.to(device)` call. This way, we are encapsulating all model-related device management in the model class itself.

Comment: Thank you. Would this be a common and conventional approach?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this will apply to your case but you can also use `.to(device)` after the model has been initialized:

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

class myModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.foo = nn.Linear(100, 100)


model = myModel().to(device)

print(next(model.parameters()).device) # "device(type='cuda', index=0)" if on GPU else "device(type='cpu')"
```

It's also fine to include the `device` variable as a parameter within your model class.  Here is another implementation option:

```
class myModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @property
    def device(self):
        return next(self.parameters()).device

model = myModel()
print(model.device) # "device(type='cuda', index=0)" if on GPU else "device(type='cpu')"
```